# How to add True or False values to a dataframe column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis, data-cleaning

Can somebody suggest me on how to create True or False values in a data-frame?
For example I have a data-frame like below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[0, 1, 2, 3], "b":[1, 4, 7, 9],"c":["In, Out", "Out", "In, Out", "In, Out"]})
print(df)

a  b  c

0  1  In, Out

1  4  Out

2  7  In, Out

3  9  In, Out
```

I would like to edit this one like below

```
a  b  In        Out

0  1  True      True

1  4  False     True

2  7  False     False

3  9  True      True
```

Comment: can you explain the logic a little more? what defines `True` and `False` ?

Comment: Is that a list of strings `["In","Out"]`, or the literal string `"In, Out"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If want convert column to boolean by indicators (`True` if exist value) then use [`Series.str.get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html) with [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) and [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) for extract column:

```
df = df.join(df.pop('c').str.get_dummies(', ').astype(bool))
print (df)
   a  b     In   Out
0  0  1   True  True
1  1  4  False  True
2  2  7   True  True
3  3  9   True  True
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming dataframe called df, can do it by list comprehension.

```
df['In'] = ['In' in x for x in df['c']]
df['Out'] = ['Out' in x for x in df['c']]

df.drop('c', axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks for your input and time @MCF :)

Answer (score -1):

If you are checking by keyword `In` in column `c` then I think you can use this:

```
df["out"] = df[df["c"] == "In"]
```

Comment: Thanks for for your input and time @Paulius Baranuskas :)